# VueJS getting posts from Wordpress with Axios and Composition API giving error "Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component"

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

Yet another question regarding the same project.

The following Options API code works flawlessly, no errors and everything shows correctly:

```
<script lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      postsUrl: "https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/news",

      posts: [] as any[],
      isLoading: false,
      regex: /(<([^>]+)>)/gi,
      errorCaught: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      axios
        .get(this.postsUrl, { params: { _embed: true } })
        .then((response) => {
          this.posts = response.data;
          console.log("Pages retrieved!");
          console.log(this.posts);
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          if (error) {
            this.isLoading = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.errorCaught = true;
            }, 1100);
          }
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getPosts();
  },
};
</script>
```

and the template:

```
<template>
  <div class="news-container">
    <div class="loading">
      <transition name="fadeLoading">
        <div v-if="isLoading">Loading...</div>
      </transition>
      <transition name="fadeLoading">
        <div v-if="errorCaught">There was an error loading news</div>
      </transition>
    </div>
    <div v-if="posts">
      <ul v-for="id in posts" :key="id" ref="posts">
        <h1>
          <router-view :to="id.slug" tag="div" key="page.id"
            >{{ id.title.rendered }}
          </router-view>
        </h1>

        <p class="date">{{ id.date }}</p>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

But, when I do this with Composition API, there is an error:

> Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component . This means you
> have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus
> recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component
> template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

After playing around with commenting out parts, seems like the `posts` constant gets the `response.data` correctly, but before that, it populates itself **208** times unnecessarily, which is btw **52times** as many, as posts I have in the `response.data`:
[image: 208times]

```
const posts = ref([] as any);
```

Could you tell me why this happens and how to get rid of this error message?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Simply setting `posts.value = response.data` can not trigger 208 rerenderings by itself - something else is causing this. Also, your `v-if="posts"` will always evaluate to true unless you init with `const posts = ref(null)`

Comment: I played around with it a bit more, seems like the following happens:
my v-for loop div `<ul v-for="id in posts" :key="id" ref="posts">` loops for posts data, which is not populated yet, yet it is, since its a ref. That happens until the axios finishes the .get, and then I append that to posts.value.
Interesting thing again, this does not happen when using Options API and the data(), methods, etc structure.

Comment: So the `posts` ref is initialized with an empty array - and thus the `v-for` generates no `UL` items. When the Axios completes - if you assign the result to `posts.value` then it will generate 1 re-render. But if you perform 208 times `posts.value.push(some_item)` then probably this will trigger 208 re-renderings of the component.